# Setting a left style CSS attribute to move a slider in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a slider effect in javascript by adjusting the CSS left property and the  setInterval function in Javascript. 
My code looks like this

```
<body onload="move('imagetag');">
    <div id="container">
        <img id="imagetag" src="img.jpg" style="left:40px; position:absolute;">
    </div>
    <script>
        function move(tag) {
            var target = document.getElementById(tag).style;
            var current = target.left;

            function moveObject() {
                current = parseInt(current) + 10 + 'px';
                console.log(current);
                setTimeout(moveObject, 1000);
            }
            setTimeout(moveObject, 1000);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

the console.log prints out the correct value but it's not reflected in the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because you do not write the style, you just read it and edit the value itself but not the target.left

```
            function move(tag) {    
                var target = document.getElementById(tag).style;
                var current = target.left;                  
                function moveObject () {
                    current = parseInt(current) + 10 + 'px';
                    console.log(current);
                    target.left = current;  // <- 
                    setTimeout( moveObject,1000);
                }
                setTimeout( moveObject, 1000);
            }
```

Comment: in javascript this `current = target.left` is a copy not a reference

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. what will be the work around then? do i use the reference i.e target.left instead of current ?